# init a thread which is a member variable inside of an constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, constructor

I am trying to write a ResourceCach which should have a thread which loads and unloads objects of different types. I started with the idea of having a thread as member variable and a list wich `std::string`s as which represent the path to the files to load / unload. So there is also an method called work() which should be executed by the thread. But well enaugh talk.

The question is:
**How to i init the thread inside of my Constructor?**

.h

```
class ResourceCach
{
public:
    ResourceCach();
    ~ResourceCach();
    void init();
    bool stopThread();
    void load(std::string path);
void unload(std::string path);
private: 

    thread m_worker; // ptr? reference? which would be right?
    vector<std::string> m_toLoad;
    vector<std::string> m_toUnload;

    void work();
};
```

And the cpp should be something like this (this does not work)

```
ResourceCach::ResourceCach()
{
    init();
}


ResourceCach::~ResourceCach()
{
}

void ResourceCach::init()
{
    m_worker(ResourceCach::work, "ResourceCach-Thread");
}

void ResourceCach::work(){

}

bool ResourceCach::stopThread(){
    if (m_worker.joinable())
    {
        m_worker.join();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

We are talking about the `std::thread`. So how can i do this? And is it a good "way" to start this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply initialise it in the usual way, in the initialiser list:

```
ResourceCach::ResourceCach() : m_worker([this]{work();}) {}
```

although, if you do that, you should declare it last to make sure all the other member variables are initialised before the thread can access them.

If you want to defer it, then leave it default-initialised, and move another thread to it later:

```
m_worker = std::thread([this]{work();});
```

NOTE: I'm assuming it's `std::thread`, although the constructor you're trying to call looks non-standard. If it's some non-standard thread type, then this answer may not apply.

Comment: so i can put that into the init and it should be fine. If i stop the thread with .join() i can call the init agian andit get spawned fine? `(m_worker = std::thread([this]{work(); },"ResourceCach");)` You are right that it is std::thread. i just found something like that online and didnt get it working

Comment: @BennX: Yes, it should be fine to put that in `init`, and to do it again (after joining) to respawn.

Comment: Thanks alot. Thats what i was looking for. Hope that the approach of an ResourceCach should be fine. Didnt thought about the lambda init somehow